# Intentional type mismatch in Fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran, legacy-code

I'd like to turn a legacy Fortran code into modern Fortran compliant code, so I can turn on compiler warnings, interface checking, etc. At this stage I don't want to change the functionality, just make it work as close as possible to what it was, and still keep compilers happy.

My current problem is that the code at many places passes arrays of the wrong types, e.g. a real array to a subroutine that has an integer dummy argument. This is not a bug per se in the code, since it is intentional and it works as intended (at least in common configurations). Now, how could I do the same and while keeping the code compliant? Consider the following example:

```
program cast
implicit none
double precision :: a(10)

call fill_dble(a,10)
call print_dble(a,10)
call fill_int(a,10)
!call fill_int(cast_to_int(a),10)
call print_dble(a,10)
call print_int(a(1),10)
!call print_int(cast_to_int(a),10)
call print_dble(a(6),5)

contains

function cast_to_int(a) result(b)
use iso_c_binding
implicit none
double precision, target :: a(*)
integer, pointer :: b(:)
call c_f_pointer(c_loc(a(1)), b, [1])
end function

end program

subroutine fill_dble(b,n)
implicit none
integer :: n, i
double precision :: b(n)
do i = 1, n
  b(i) = i
end do
end subroutine

subroutine print_dble(b,n)
implicit none
integer :: n
double precision :: b(n)
write(6,'(10es12.4)') b
end subroutine

subroutine fill_int(b,n)
implicit none
integer :: n, b(n), i
do i = 1, n
  b(i) = i
end do
end subroutine

subroutine print_int(b,n)
implicit none
integer :: n, b(n)
write(6,'(10i4)') b
end subroutine
```

When I compile it and run it (gfortran 4.8 or ifort 18), I get, as expected:

```
  1.0000E+00  2.0000E+00  3.0000E+00  4.0000E+00  5.0000E+00  6.0000E+00  7.0000E+00  8.0000E+00  9.0000E+00  1.0000E+01
  4.2440-314  8.4880-314  1.2732-313  1.6976-313  2.1220-313  6.0000E+00  7.0000E+00  8.0000E+00  9.0000E+00  1.0000E+01
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  6.0000E+00  7.0000E+00  8.0000E+00  9.0000E+00  1.0000E+01
```

The first half of the real array is corrupted with integers (because integers are half the size), but when printed as integers the "right" values are there. But this is non-compliant code. When I try to fix it by activating the `cast_to_int` function (and disabling the calls without it) I get indeed something that compiles without warning, and with gfortran I get the same result. With ifort, however, I get:

```
  1.0000E+00  2.0000E+00  3.0000E+00  4.0000E+00  5.0000E+00  6.0000E+00  7.0000E+00  8.0000E+00  9.0000E+00  1.0000E+01
  1.0000E+00  2.0000E+00  3.0000E+00  4.0000E+00  5.0000E+00  6.0000E+00  7.0000E+00  8.0000E+00  9.0000E+00  1.0000E+01
   0********   0   5   6   7   8   9  10
  6.0000E+00  7.0000E+00  8.0000E+00  9.0000E+00  1.0000E+01
```

which I can't understand. Moreover, ifort with `-O0` crashes (and it doesn't with the other version).

I know the code is still not quite correct, because the pointer returned by `cast_to_int` is still of size 1, but I believe that should be a different problem.

What am I doing wrong, or how can I get ifort do what I want?

---

EDIT: Following @VladimirF's reply, I add, after `implicit none`:

```
subroutine fill_int(b,n)
!dec$ attributes no_arg_check :: b
integer :: n, b(n)
end subroutine
subroutine print_int(b,n)
!dec$ attributes no_arg_check :: b
integer :: n, b(n)
end subroutine
end interface
```

but compiling with warnings on still gives me an error:

```
$ ifort cast2.f90 -warn all
cast2.f90(17): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [A]
call fill_int(a,10)
--------------^
cast2.f90(20): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [A]
call print_int(a(1),10)
---------------^
compilation aborted for cast2.f90 (code 1)
```

Comment: You may use `transfer`, but you will have to somehow change the logic of the routines. I know of no portable way to achieve this with arguments. However, you should first try to understand why the original author actualy did this in the first place and how to do the same correctly (could be an X/Y problem), possibly without such hack.

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping the code compliant"?  The code certainly does not conform to the Fortran standard.

Comment: @Steve I mean as far as the compiler tells me. Without the `cast_to_int` it is obviously not conforming. I want something that behaves the same (not just give the same results) and is conforming or, at least, that gives as few warnings as possible.

Comment: @Jellby Out of curiosity, if you change "double precision, target :: a(*)" to "double precision, target :: a(:)", does ifort give the same result as gfortran when uncommenting cast_to_int() + commenting out calls w/o it?

Comment: @roygvib No, it gives the same result with `a(*)` or `a(:)`

Comment: @Jellby Hmm, I see.. thanks for trying (FWIW, PGI in hand gives the same results as gfortran)

Answer (score 1):

Intel Fortran supports the [`!dec$ attributes no_arg_check` directive](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-attributes-no-arg-check). It instructs the compiler *"that type and shape matching rules related to explicit interfaces are to be ignored"*.

*"It can be applied to an individual dummy argument name or to the routine name, in which case the option is applied to all dummy arguments in that interface."*

It should be applied to a module procedure (or an interface block), so you should move your functions and subroutines into a module.

Many other compilers have [similar directives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ATTRIBUTES-directive.html#ATTRIBUTES-directive).

---

What is wrong about your code? As a rule of thumb, **do not ever use any Fortran functions that return `pointer`s**. They are pure evil. Fortran pointers are completely different from C pointers.

When you do `call fill_int(cast_to_int(a),10)` what happens is that the expression `cast_to_int(a)` is evaluated and the result is an array. Now depending on the optimizations the compiler may choose to pass the address of the original pointer, but it may also create a copy of the result integer array and pass a copy to the subroutine.

Also, your array `a` does not have the `target` attribute, so the address used inside `cast_to_int(a)` is only valid inside the function and is not valid after it returns.

You should make the `b` inside the main program and just pass `b` instead of `a`. It will work similar to equivalence. Looking at the values stored as a different type will be not standard-conforming anyway. This form of type punning is not allowed.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid it because first, it needs writing interface blocks or modules, and second because not checking is different from explicitly doing the "conversion".

Comment: @Jellby That is really not a big restriction, I think you really want too much. What kind of conversion do you want to happen? Automagically? You cannot just reinterpret integer bit patterns as reals and expect meaningful numbers.

Comment: Perhaps you should also show the code of the original approach so that we can see what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Sure, I have no expectations about the meaning of the numbers, but the original author(s) thought it would work, and it apparently has for decades. I don't have a particular example at hand, but I have seen it in several places in the code (large, messy codebase), usually it is, as the Intel page says, memory copying routines, or reading/writing binary files, or allocating a big chunk as real, and then using some pieces of it as integers.

Comment: e.g. https://gitlab.com/Molcas/OpenMolcas/blob/master/src/cpf/cpfctl.f#L91 uses just different portions of the array `H` for arguments, while the subroutine is defined in https://gitlab.com/Molcas/OpenMolcas/blob/master/src/cpf/cupdate.f#L14 with real and integer arguments.

Comment: These "memory copying routines, or reading/writing binary files, or allocating a big chunk as real, and then using some pieces of it as integers" are perfect cases for the directives. Or just use them as external subprograms, the way they work presently. But it has nothing to do with the code in your question, at least in my opinion.

Comment: I think it's a very reduced example of "allocating a big chunk as real, and then using some pieces of it as integers".

Comment: The point is that in ""memory copying routines, or reading/writing binary files, or allocating a big chunk as real, and then using some pieces of it as integers" no conversion ever happens. But I will have a look at your example.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I should have said that when half of the array is corrupted with integers, that's OK, I don't care about those "real" values, they are only printed to check that they have actually been modified.

Comment: @Jellby This kind of hack was usually done to overcome the lack of memory allocation (use one large array as heap storage for whatever you need, integer or real, and manage the heap "by hand"). Not needed anymore.

Comment: Indeed, and for the transitinal period I recommend either the directive or to keep the subroutines external (provided the compiler does not check accross source files).

Comment: May I ask for the reason of the downvote? This really makes one reconsider spending so much time trying to help other people. Especially here where it was done almost interactively.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible general solution that seems to work. The code I have to deal with looks something like this:

```
subroutine some_subroutine(a,b,c,d,...)
real a(*),b(*),c(*),d(*)
! many more declarations, including common blocks

!...
call other_subroutine(a,b(idx),c,...)
!...

end subroutine some_subroutine

! this typically in another file:
subroutine other_subroutine(x,y,z,...)
real x(*)
integer y(*)
logical z(*)
! other declarations and common blocks

! unreadable code with calls to other procedures
! not clear which which arguments are input and output

end subroutine other_subroutine
```

I now modify it to be:

```
subroutine some_subroutine(a,b,c,d,...)
real a(*),b(*),c(*),d(*)
! many more declarations, including common blocks

call inner_sub(b,c)

contains
subroutine inner_sub(b,c)
use iso_c_binding
real, target :: b(*),c(*)
integer, pointer :: ib(:)
logical, pointer :: lc(:)

!...
call c_f_pointer(c_loc(b(idx)),ib,[1]) ! or use the actual length if I can figure it out
call c_f_pointer(c_loc(c(1)),lc,[1])
call other_subroutine(a,ib,lc,...)
nullify(ib,lc)
!...

end subroutine inner_sub

end subroutine some_subroutine
```

leaving `other_subroutine` untouched. If I use directly the `target` attribute on the outer routine, I have to add an explicit interface to anything calling it, so instead I wrap the inner code. By using `contains` I don't need to pass all variables, just those that will be "punned". The `c_f_pointer` call should be done right before the problematic call, since index variables (`idx` in the example) could be in common blocks and changed in other calls, for example.

Any pitfalls, apart from those already present in the original code?

Comment: This basicaly what I wrote: *"You should make the b inside the main program and just pass b instead of a."*

Comment: @VladimirF Indeed, though I didn't fully get it at first. Also the fact that having `target` in a dummy argument required an explicit interface had me worried for a while. I just wanted to write down the full "solution".